# How to allow edges to overlap nodes?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm looking for a way to disable edge routing during rendering of dot graphs.
Ideally this would be a per-edge option, but disabling routing altogether would be helpful as well.

The graphs I'm generating represent syntax trees with additional edges from the usage of an identifier to its declaration as shown below.

[Simple DAST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLaXr.png)

Now, this is still mostly readable, but with larger graphs the blue edges get very confusing very quickly, since dot seems to love routing them all over the place.

[Complex DAST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/218PW.png)

I would prefer if they just went in a straight (or curved) line between the two nodes, ignoring all overlap with nodes and other edges.
Unfortunately I've been unable to find a way to achieve this effect and honestly I doubt it is even possible.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983885/graphviz-allow-edge-node-overlap) has been asked before, but I decided to open a new one anyway due to the following reasons:

- I don't require the nodes to stay in a fixed position
- Apart from the blue edges, my graph is always a tree (no edge overlap to worry about)
- Running dot in multiple passes is unfortunately not an option for me
- The other question is over 6 years old, so maybe a feature was added since then

My attempts so far:

- Added "overlap=true" to the graph settings
- Added "overlap=true" to individual edges

Neither of these seems to have any effect whatsoever.

The file layout is pretty simple (excerpt):

```
digraph {
  node [shape=Mrecord];
  graph [ordering=out, overlap=true, nodesep=0.3, ranksep=1];
  ...
  # ReferenceLiteral rec
  node0 -> node40 [style=dashed, color=blue, constraint=false]
  node0 [shape=box style=filled label="rec" fillcolor="#cccccc"]
  ...
  # PortNode Record
  node28:p0:s -> node40:n
  node28:p1_0:s -> node7:n
  node28 [label="{Record|{<p0>Name|{Elements|{<p1_0>1}}}}"]
  ...
  # DeclarationLiteral rec
  node40 [shape=box style=filled label="rec" fillcolor="#cccccc"]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like what I wanted to do isn't possible... I ended up [color-coding](https://i.imgur.com/K0Om6NI.png) corresponding nodes and edges to achive some visual clarity.